# Loading gif image from sd card

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to load gif image inside a jetpack composable function. I see static image. But not the frame animations (Using CoilImage library). Anyone here has successfully loaded a gif file from SD card?

Comment: Did you add the Coil extension GIF library?

Comment: Yes I did add it. Is it working for you @CommonsWare

Comment: I have not tried it. [Chris Banes seems to suggest that it should work](https://github.com/chrisbanes/accompanist/tree/main/coil#gifs), but perhaps he was focused on non-animated GIFs. You might want to post a [mcve] showing what you tried; perhaps we can point out some flaw in your approach. Or, create a project that easily reproduces the problem, then file an issue against Accompanist.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with below code. Problem is, it is not animating all the time. I saw it was not at all animating few times when I launch the application.

```
@Composable
fun loadGif(){

    val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this)
        .componentRegistry {
            if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                add(ImageDecoderDecoder())
            } else {
                add(GifDecoder())
            }
        }
        // customize the ImageLoader as needed
        .build()

    Providers(AmbientImageLoader provides imageLoader) {
        // This will automatically use the value of AmbientImageLoader
        CoilImage(
           //data = "https://media.giphy.com/media/qVmhGFxmtr2sU/giphy.gif"
             data = File("//sdcard/Android/app/anim/my.gif")
           
        )
    }

}
```